# how to prevent creation of a new table in a database in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there any way i can prevent creation of table in mysql using triggers as it is possible in tsql like:

```
   create trigger demo 
   on database after create_table
   as 
   begin
   print 'creation of new tables not allowed'
   rollback transaction
   end 
   go
```

i went through the reference manual on trigger on mysql site.But could not find this.Is this possible in mysql

Comment: That feature does not exist. Out of curiosity, what exact problem are you trying to prevent?

Comment: I would also like to know why this even occured to you

Answer (score 4):

MySQL triggers only exist for table changes, not on databases.

If you want to prevent a user from creating a table, you can [revoke](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html) the `CREATE` privilege on your database :

```
REVOKE CREATE ON database.* FROM 'username'@'hostname'
```